# How can I use unirest API calls in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unirest

I'm working with `unirest` API calls and React for the first time and I'm having trouble implementing a `unirest` call. While it works in a simple Node.js program, if I try to plug the code below into a React.js file and work with it, I'm unable to get any results for some reason, as I just get an undefined object back.

[image: console description]

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
unirest.get(--insert url here--)
.header("X-Mashape-Key", --insert key here--)
.header("X-Mashape-Host", "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition- 
v1.p.mashape.com")
.end(function (result) {
  console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
});
```

However, when I plug this into a barebones Node.js file, I get an object back with the values I want. I've been struggling with this for days -- does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is how I tried to implement this in React:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
var unirest = require('unirest');

class Kitchen extends React.Component {
  callApi() {
    unirest.get(--insert api url--)
    .header("X-Mashape-Key", --insert api key--)
    .header("X-Mashape-Host", "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition- 
    v1.p.mashape.com")
    .end(function (result) {
      console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
  });  

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="ingredient-info">
        {this.callApi()}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

EDIT 2: Here is what the expected Object body looks like:

```
[ { id: 556470,
    title: 'Apple fritters',
    image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/556470-312x231.jpg',
    imageType: 'jpg',
    usedIngredientCount: 3,
    missedIngredientCount: 0,
    likes: 243 },
  { id: 73474,
    title: 'Apple Turnovers',
    image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/73474-312x231.jpg',
    imageType: 'jpg',
    usedIngredientCount: 3,
    missedIngredientCount: 0,
    likes: 48 },
  { id: 47950,
    title: 'Cinnamon Apple Crisp',
    image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/47950-312x231.jpg',
    imageType: 'jpg',
    usedIngredientCount: 3,
    missedIngredientCount: 0,
    likes: 35 } ]
```

Comment: Please show a small example to illustrate how you have tried to do this with React

Comment: Sorry; updated the OP.

Comment: `callAPI()` does not `return` anything so it defaults to returning `undefined`.

Comment: Hm, but it should still print something in the console, right? I'm getting an `undefined` object in the console for the `result.body`, but `result.status` and `result.headers` show up just fine in the console.

Comment: Good point. I'm not familiar with unirest, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far regardless!

Comment: Can you show an example of the expected body?

Comment: Good idea; updated the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unirest is for Node (server-side)... Client (browser) has fetch baked in...

Here is a simple get request to https://randomuser.me/ example:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { users: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10&nat=us")
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        const users = data.results;
        this.setState({ users: users });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.users.map((user, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <div>{user.name.first}</div>
              <img src={user.picture.thumbnail} alt="" />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a working example of the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/0yw5n3mm7n